# Что представляет собой покупка доменного имени с технической точки зрения?

Tags: хостинг, домен

Несмотря на свою деятельность в веб-разработке, пока ещё не достиг глубокого понимания сущности интернета и этот вопрос - один из шагов на пути к осмыслению.

В Википедии, в статье ["Интернет"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82#.D0.AE.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.8B_.D0.B8_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.89.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B0) среди юридических аспектов и общих свойств интернета приведено:

> У Интернета нет собственника, так как он является совокупностью сетей,
>   которые имеют различную географическую принадлежность.

Если это прочитает человек, не имевший ранее дело с интернетом, он наверняка может прийти в выводу, что всё, что нужно для опубликования своего сайта в интернет - подключённый к интернету компьютер и никаких хостинговых компаний и регистраторов доменных имён.

Насколько я уже знаю, для того, чтобы начать "транслировать" свой сайт в интернет, нужно открыть 80-ый порт (например, с помощью веб-сервера Apache, который является ПО). Конечно, безопасность персонального для компьютера такой трансляции - уже другой вопрос. Но что представляет собой *технически* покупка доменного имени? Почему мы не можем присовить произвольное доменное имя своему сайту хотя бы в пределах некоторых доменных зон и транслировать его со своего компьютера под этим доменным именем? Выходит, у интернета всё-таки есть собственник, который наделяет правом регистраторов доменов продавать эти доменные имена?

Comment: Я думаю имелось ввиду что интернет состоит из множества сетей и каждая из них кому-то принадлежит, а в целом эта паутина не может контролироваться одной орагнизацией. Что-то вроде акционерного общества получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственника у Интернета нет, но есть координатор. Исторически сложилось так, что координатором является [*ICANN*](https://www.icann.org/ru).

Почему же мы не можем просто так взять произвольное имя? Потому что это имя должно быть известно всем и однозначно разрешаться в IP-адрес компьютера. Для этого служит *DNS*. И именно за внесение записи в эту глобальную для всего мира таблицу соответствия имён и IP-адресов вы и платите при покупке доменного имени.

Можно ли не платить? Можно. Например, можно вписать соответствие имени и IP в локальный файл `hosts`. Но тогда сайт будет доступен только с тех компьютеров, где мы этот файл изменили. Можно поднять свой собственный DNS-сервер, на котором указать наше имя и использовать этот сервер для всех компьютеров, которым нужен наш сайт. Но вряд ли произвольный пользователь в Сети согласится на это. К тому же, если каждый сайт сделает такой сервер, то для клиента будет абсолютно неудобно этот адрес DNS-сервера постоянно переписывать. (Но это хорошее решение для внутренних сетей организаций.) Поэтому большинство предпочитает заплатить и не мучиться.

Есть ещё один способ получить имя бесплатно. Надо найти того, кто уже купил имя второго уровня (или более низкого), например, `example.org`, договориться с ним и попросить внести запись более низкого уровня, например, `vasya.example.org`. Это можно сделать, поскольку владелец домена может прописывать любые записи для всех поддоменов.

Comment: Надо добавить, что некоторые домены второго уровня можно получить и за бесплатно. Например, [.tk](http://dot.tk/), [.ga](http://my.ga/), [.ml](http://www.point.ml/en/index.html), [.cf](http://dot.cf/) и другие

Answer (score 2):

Технически, для сайта и правда достаточно подключенного к интернету компьютера с открытым портом. Вот только на такой сайт посетителям придется ходить по IP-адресу.

А IP-адрес, вообще говоря, является собственностью провайдера и может быть изменен. В этом случае придется как-то рассказывать всем посетителям свой новый адрес.

*Замечание. Вообще говоря, существует возможность приобрести себе постоянный IP-адрес - но это доступно только юридическим лицам и будет стоить дороже доменного имени.*

Один из способов подобного "рассказа" - это DNS. Служба, которая преобразует те самые доменные имена в IP-адреса. Право создавать домены второго уровня имеют *регистраторы*. Вот им-то и надо платить за домен.

После покупки доменное имя становится вашим - пока вы за него платите. В частности, это означает что никто без вашего ведома не может отобрать его у вас (кроме как через суд в некоторых случаях).

Владея доменов второго уровня вы можете создавать любое число доменов третьего и ниже уровней бесплатно. Иногда для этого надо поднимать свой DNS-сервер и открывать 53й порт, иногда не надо (зависит от регистратора).

Существуют также сервисы, раздающие бесплатные доменные имена третьего уровня. Но, вообще говоря, вашими такие доменные имена также не являются.

---

Технически покупка доменного имени заключается в том, что вы платите регистратору за то, что он внесет запись о соответствии некоторого имени вашему IP-адресу в некоторый общий список.

Comment: Хотелось бы отметить, что многие провайдеры предоставляют услугу "статический IP" частным лицам и стоит она не так уж и дорого. А отнять имя можно и без суда. Многие регистраторы просто блочат имя при получении абуз. Да и реалии России в виде Роскомнадзора тоже никто не отменял.

Comment: @kff тем не менее, статический IP остается собственностью провайдера. Нельзя взять этот IP и пойти с ним к другому провайдеру. Если использовать его для своего сайта напрямую - сайт оказывается навсегда привязан к конкретному провайдеру.